# Castle Windsor 3.1 Missing Method Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, castle-windsor

Attempting to install all of my seperate installers from a test assembly keeps throwing a

```
 "`{"Method not found: 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration1<!0> Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration1.DependsOn(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Dependency)'."}`"
```

Despite the fact that the code runs perfectly from the Console application/Windsows service and the references of the two projects are identical:

```
Castle.Core
Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport
Castle.Facilities.Logging
Castle.Facilities.QuartzIntegration
Castle.Services.Logging.NLogIntegration
Castle.Windsor
```

Does anyone know a reason why a test assembly calling the building of the windsor container thusly:

```
   this.Container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter())
       .Install(FromAssembly.Named("Assembly.WindowsService", 
                new CustomWindsorInstallerFactory()));
```

fails on any code that references the "DependsOn" method, such as:

```
container.Register(
    Component
         .For<ISftpRepository, ISftpFileStoreRepository, AbstractSftpFileStoreRepository>()
         .ImplementedBy<ConcreteSftpRepository>()
         .Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll)
         .DependsOn(
              Dependency.OnConfigValue("host", config.Host),
```

or:

```
.ConfigureFor<QuartzJob>(
      x => 
      x.DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IService>().Eq("intraService")))
```

NB: please note all the installation classes work perfectly when running under the main application, this is purely a situational case when running unit tests.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Has nobody ever had this before? Its holding back my development unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a reference to Assembly.WindowsService in your test project? Could you instead of FromAssembly.Named try a method which does not use a string ?

Comment: @Marwijn All references are present to Windsor and local class libraries. This has been tested with every FromAssmbly method with the same results, magic string'd or otherwise unfortunetely...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an older version of Windsor somewhere that overwrites the new one when deploying

Comment: Thanks for the response - I will check this again